# Iterate through XML with xmlstarlet

Tags: shell, xmlstarlet

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test-report>
<testsuite>
<test name="RegisterConnection1Tests">
<testcase name="testRregisterConnection001"></testcase>
<testcase name="testRegisterConnection002"></testcase>
</test>
<test name="RegisterConnection2Tests">
<testcase name="testRregisterConnection001"></testcase>
<testcase name="testRegisterConnection002"></testcase>
</test>
</testsuite>
</test-report>
```

And I want the output:

```
RegisterConnection1Tests,testRregisterConnection001
RegisterConnection1Tests,testRregisterConnection002
RegisterConnection2Tests,testRregisterConnection001
RegisterConnection2Tests,testRregisterConnection002
```

I'm confused as to how to show the children as I expected

`xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'test-report/testsuite/test' -v '@name' -v '//testcase/@name' -n $1` to work, though it only inputs:

```
RegisterConnection1TeststestRregisterConnection001
RegisterConnection2TeststestRregisterConnection001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add the missing comma you can add another `-v "','"`
<del>In your second column you are selecting with an absolute xpath expression from the root element and not from the element matched by the template, the double slashes are wrong.</del> Since you want one line per testcase I would iterate over the testcase elements and then add the name attribute of the parent element like this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'test-report/testsuite/test/testcase' -v '../@name' -v "','" -v '@name' -n $1
```

Comment: No, still wrong.

    $ xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'test-    report/testsuite/test' -v '@name' -v "','" -v 'testcase/@name' -n   test.xml 
    RegisterConnection1Tests,testRregisterConnection001
RegisterConnection2Tests,testRregisterConnection001

Comment: ah, didn't realise you could do a ../ parent thing like that. Clever!

Comment: `-o ,` is equivalent to `-v "','"`