# Xmlstarlet, multiple elements and date exclusion

Tags: xml, linux, bash, terminal, xmlstarlet

I've never used xmlstarlet so I'm just going to keep it simple with input and desired output, and hopefully I can learn something from the answers that are posted.

Input:

```
<channel>
    <title>
    <link>http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/</link>
    <description></description>
    <ttl>60</ttl>
    <category>Sports</category>

        <item>
             <sport><![CDATA[Women's Soccer]]></sport>
             <opponent><![CDATA[South Carolina (Exhibition)]]></opponent>
             <location><![CDATA[Columbia, S.C.]]></location>
             <date>08/09/2012</date>
             <time>7:00 PM</time>
             <tv><![CDATA[]]></tv>
             <tournamentname><![CDATA[]]></tournamentname>
             <homeaway>A</homeaway>
        </item>     

        <item>
             <sport><![CDATA[Men's Soccer]]></sport>
             <opponent><![CDATA[Ohio State (Exhibition)]]></opponent>
             <location><![CDATA[Fort Wayne, Ind.]]></location>
             <date>08/17/2012</date>
             <time>7:00 PM</time>
             <tv><![CDATA[]]></tv>
             <tournamentname><![CDATA[]]></tournamentname>
             <homeaway>H</homeaway>
        </item>     

        <item>
             <sport><![CDATA[Women's Soccer]]></sport>
             <opponent><![CDATA[William and Mary]]></opponent>
             <location><![CDATA[Williamsburg, Va.]]></location>
             <date>08/17/2012</date>
             <time>7:00 PM</time>
             <tv><![CDATA[]]></tv>
             <tournamentname><![CDATA[]]></tournamentname>
             <homeaway>A</homeaway>
        </item>
```

Desired output:

```
Women's Soccer Away @ South Carolina (Exhibition) at 7:00 PM
Men's Soccer Home vs Ohio State at 7:00 PM
Women's Soccer Away @ William and Mary at 7:00 PM
```

A few things that make this not just straightforward data manipulation

1) I'd like to remove all data that doesn't have a `<date>` of the current date

2) As you can see from the desired output, I'd like for the A result of the element `<homeaway>` to show the text 'Away @' and I'd like for the H tag to show the text 'Home vs'

Thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you could just help me get started?  The file is stored in /tmp/rss.xml.  I know I want to get to the rss/channel/item level.

Comment: The South Carolina game has a different date than the other 2, but you listed them all, which seems to contradict requirement 1...

Comment: This is just a sample, there are about 50 items in the actual xml file, but yes I'd like to remove any games that don't have a date of today.

Comment: Except for the date, this looks like a good place to start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3069031/iterate-through-xml-with-xmlstarlet . As a workaround, I would use cmds to output date field as well, then manually delete the old dates. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
xmlstarlet sel --text -t \
    -m '//channel[category="Sports"]/item[date="'$(date +%m/%d/%Y)'"]' \
    -v sport -o ' ' \
    --if 'homeaway="H"' -o 'Home vs' --else -o 'Away @' -b -o ' ' \
    -v opponent -o ' ' \
    -o 'at ' -v time --nl \
    /tmp/rss.xml
```

- -m (or --match) starts a foreach loop
- -b (or --break) means endif (actually it's a general endblock or closing brace)